# Java: add listener to the processor

Tags: java, hardware, listener

how can I add a listener to the computer's processor? I want the mouse cursor to change when the processing is hight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to have to drop to native code to get the CPU info.  [Here is an article on doing that](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2002-11/01-qa-1108-cpu.html).

You would have to write a class that then makes use of that native call and provides the API you want for the listener.

Edit:

Hmmm... you might also check out http://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home.

Comment: I expect something as easy as the OutOfMemory warning system - http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue092.html

Comment: thanks for the update! I would like they introduce that in the JDK, by the way.